# numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

Student1= [1,2]
test11= np.array([])
np.clip(0,1,20)
NOF=int(2) 
print("Enter test score, students name are (1,2,3, etc): ")
for i in range(NOF):
    data=int(input())
    test11.append(data)
total=0
for value in test11:
    total=total+value
print("The sum of all", total)
```

LIST VERSION

```
import numpy as np

Student1= [1,2]
test11= []
NOF=int(2) 
print("Enter test score, students name are (1,2,3, etc): ")
for i in range(NOF):
    data=int(input())
    test11.append(data)
total=0
for value in test11:
    total=total+value
print("The sum of all", total)
```

This keeps erroring 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append.' I wanna be able to add user data, to the array test11. Works fine without making test11 a numpy array. But I wanna be able to limit the size of the number to 20. Any ideas? Plz make it simple.

ERROR CODE:
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 10, in 
test11.append(data)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: `numpy.ndarray` objects indeed do not have an `append` method. Why don't you ust use a `list`?

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: That `np.clip` line does nothing for you.  Reread its docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seams to work. I changed a few lines again and marked them.

```
import numpy as np

Student1= [1,2]
test11= np.array([0])
NOF=int(2) 
print("Enter test score, students name are (1,2,3, etc): ")
data = None
while data is None:  # Remove this if you want the program to end if an error occurres.
    for i in range(NOF):
        try:  # Be sure the input is a int.
            data=np.array([int(input())])
            if data > 20:  # Be sure the input is <= 20.
                data = None  # If greater then 20. Turn data into None
                test11 = np.array([0])  # Empty the array.
                print("Error")
                break  # Then break out of the loop
            test11 = np.append(data, test11)
        except ValueError:
            data = None  # If it is not a int, data will trun into None
            test11 = np.array([0])  # Empty the array.
            print("Error")
            break

if data is not None:  # If data is not None then find the sum.
    total=0
    for value in test11:
        total = test11.sum()  # Use the sum fuction, though  total=total+value  will also work.
    print("The sum of all", total)
```

List version.

```
# import numpy as np

Student1= [1,2]
test11= []
NOF=int(2) 
print("Enter test score, students name are (1,2,3, etc): ")
data = None  # Assign ahead of time.
while data is None:  # Remove this if you want the program to end if an 
error occurres.
    for i in range(NOF):
        try:  # Be sure the input is a int.
            data=int(input())
            if data > 20:  # Be sure the input is <= 20.
                data = None  # If greater then 20. Turn data into None
                test11.clear()  # Clear the list if an error occurres.
                print("Error")
                break  # Then break out of the loop
            test11.append(data)
        except ValueError:
            data = None  # If it is not a int, data will trun into None
            test11.clear()  # Clear the list if an error occurres.
            print("Error")
            break

if data is not None:  # If data is not None then find the sum.
    total=0
    for value in test11:
        total=total+value
    print("The sum of all", total)
```

This is as compacted as I could make it, without changing the entire thing, and keeping it similar to what you started with.

Now the user can't use a number over 20, or any letters, or an error will appear.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say it correctly. The clip function is useless coz I would like the code to error if the user types a number bigger then 20

Comment: if you could help with that great. If not I thank you a lot for helping me implement the np.

Comment: We discourage the use of `np.append`.  List append is faster and easier to use right.

Comment: On top of hpauli's comment I would like to add: you do not need to create an array to append a number to array. And your second for loop is irrelevant! The loop is doing same thing repeatedly without any purpose. Besides you do not need to set `total=0` before a loop that you are going to assign a new value.

Comment: I was told to use an array not a list

Comment: Thx again a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays doesn't have 'append' method, they are supposed to be created with the shape and length that you will need. So in your case, the best way would be to make a list, append the values, and then creating the array:

```
import numpy as np 
Student1= [1,2] 
test11= []
np.clip(0,1,20) 
NOF=int(2) 
print("Enter test score, students name are (1,2,3, etc): ") 
for i in range(NOF): 
    data=int(input()) 
    test11.append(data)

test11 = np.array(test11)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace you line with `np.append`:

```
np.append(test11,data)
```

But appending to numpy array is costlier than appending to a list. I would suggest use `list` structure with `append` and at the end convert your list to numpy array using `np.array`

Here is a list version:

```
import numpy as np

Student1= [1,2]
test11= []
np.clip(0,1,20)
NOF=int(2) 
print("Enter test score, students name are (1,2,3, etc): ")
for i in range(NOF):
    data=int(input())
    test11.append(data)
test11 = np.array(test11)
total = test11.sum()
print("The sum of all", total)
```

Comment: When I replace it with 'np.append(test11,data)' it doesn't add up anymore :(

Comment: I will go ahead an try the list method

Comment: Did the list but where do I type the np.array into

Comment: @GlitterPony Added the list version to post

Comment: But when I use the list I can't limit the size of the number to 20 (not the size of the list)

Comment: @GlitterPony I am not sure what you mean at all. Is that what `np.clip(0,1,20)` meant to do? That line is basically doing nothing in your code. If you want to limit inout to below 20, you need a if statement. If you want to filter the entered numbers above 20, you need to use it on the `test11` array.

Comment: So what I want to happen is so the test score is out of 100 and I don't want the user to be able to type a number bigger, if he does I want it to error. HOW, I don't know how to do it

Comment: You need sth like `if data>100: data=input('please enter a number lower than 100)`